# Fusion table query : zoom on a marker from an external link

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to create links from a text to a marker in a google fusion map. More precisely, I want the map to refresh and zoom on the location selected.

A picture will be easier to understand:
http://projeteurope.free.fr/
For example, if you click on "Akrame" on the right side of the page, the map should zoom on the point (which already exist in the fusion table, and is 19 Rue Lauriston,  75016 Paris)

I've look at different topics and websites, but I don't understand how to do that (I'm a total beginner in javascript)
[Fusion Table + Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428323/fusion-table-google-maps)
or http://alamatku.com/cari?query=UPS&area=jakarta
or [Google Fusion Tables With Maps - Link Table field to Map Info Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748211/google-fusion-tables-with-maps-link-table-field-to-map-info-window)

I just want the map to zoom on a specific market, not to create a new layer with only the marker.

Many thanks if you have any clues!
Robin

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GViz (the google visualization library)](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#Query) to query the fusion table and zoom the map in on the marker.

CODE:

```
function changeQuery(term) {
  layer.setOptions({query:{select:'Latitude', /* was 'Latitude,Longitude', used to work... */
                           from:FT_TableID,
                           where:"Nom contains "+term
                           }

 });

  // zoom and center map on query results
  //set the query using the parameter
  var queryText = encodeURIComponent("SELECT 'Latitude', 'Longitude' FROM "+FT_TableID+" WHERE 'Nom' contains '"+term+"'");
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);

  //set the callback function
  query.send(zoomTo);
}

function zoomTo(response) {
if (!response) {
  alert('no response');
  return;
}
if (response.isError()) {
  alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
  return;
} 
  FTresponse = response;
  //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
  //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
  numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
  numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for(i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0)),
          parseFloat(response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 1)));
      bounds.extend(point);
  }
  // zoom to the bounds, if you have only one result, 
  // you may want to do a map.setCenter; map.setZoom to specify the behavior
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

[example/proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_GViz_zoom2MarkerA.html)

Comment: Hi Geocodezip, Dr Molle, 
I was working on this library on Dr.Molle advices, but I was (really) far from the result actually!
Thanks A LOT Geocodezip!
It's very nice of you to implement the example. It's exactly what I was looking for.
If I may ask you more thing, I'm now trying to have the infowindows opens automatically when someone clicks on the name. I've look at that https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/open_infowindow?hl=fr, but I'm unable to find where to put the code, since it's getting complicated for me... 
Thanks a lot anyway!!

Comment: If you want to open the infoWindow from the sidebar click, I would suggest implementing the click listener yourself, and querying the table for the contents.  [Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html)

Comment: Hi Geocodezip, thanks for your help. Sorry for the delay, been away from my computer for a while... I'm working on it now!

Comment: Hi everyone!
I've been able to implement the first part well as you can see (http://projeteurope.free.fr/) but there is one silly thing: I can't enter a name which contain a ' (like in L'ardoise). I think it intefere with the code at this point : WHERE 'Nom' contains '"+term+"'"). I've checked with other signs and it works. Many thanks if you have any ideas on this...

Comment: Looks like a [common problem](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=escape+single+quotes+in+javascript), have you looked through those answers for one you can use?

Comment: I have, but I have to say I don't understand how to implement it in my case. I also looked at https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/autocomplete?hl=fr where the code handles it. It's simpler with something like "replace(/'/g, '\\\'');" but cant get it to work for now